# Cant convert to list of object

Tags: c#

I am having a methong that gets values of properties or gets values of nested properties, this part is working fine but I wanted to add collection to string in case some property is a collection and i seem to have a problem with that:

Code:

```c#
public static object GetNestedPropValue<TObject>(TObject obj, string propName)
{
    string[] nestedObjectProp = propName.Split('.');
    string[] childProperties = nestedObjectProp.Skip(1).ToArray();

    string parentProp = nestedObjectProp.FirstOrDefault();

    foreach (string property in childProperties)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        PropertyInfo info = obj.GetType().GetProperty(parentProp);

        if (info == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        object nestedObject = info.GetValue(obj);

        if(childProperties.Count() == 1)
        {
            Type checkNestedType = nestedObject.GetType();

            if (IsICollection(checkNestedType) && IsIEnumerable(checkNestedType))
            {
                var nestedObjectValues = nestedObject as List<object>;

                return string.Join(", ", nestedObjectValues
                    .Select(i => i.GetType().GetProperty(childProperties.FirstOrDefault()).GetValue(nestedObject))
                    .ToArray());                   
            }
            return nestedObject.GetType().GetProperty(childProperties.FirstOrDefault()).GetValue(nestedObject);
        }

        GetNestedPropValue(nestedObject, string.Join(".", childProperties.Skip(1)));
    }

    return null;
}
```

problem is here:

```c#
var nestedObjectValues = nestedObject as List<object>;

return string.Join(", ", nestedObjectValues
    .Select(i => i.GetType().GetProperty(childProperties.FirstOrDefault()).GetValue(nestedObject))
    .ToArray());
```

When I try to type to list of object it gives me null, what seems to be the problem?

Comment: Obviously `nestedObject` is not a `List<object>`. This question can't be answered without knowing the definition of the source type and the source property referred to be `info`. The simplest way to find out is to inspect the value in the debugger.

Comment: try : var nestedObjectValues = nestedObject.ToList();

Comment: @jdweng : nestedObject is explicitly typed as `object`, `nestedObject.ToList()` will not compile

Comment: So changed to : var nestedObject = info.GetValue(obj);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nestedObject` is simply NOT a `List<object>`, so `nestedObject as List<object>` returns null.

Being a collection type and being enumerable certainly doesn't mean the type is `List<T>` for some T. And even then, a `List<T>`is not directly castable to a `List<object>` anyway (except obviously if T is `object`).

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but inspecting types through reflection before trying to cast objects to a loose guessed type feels very weird to me.